# Obtener valores de un nodo con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo con JS y estoy intentando obtener los valores de un nodo(cosa que no tengo idea como hacerlo). Mi idea es que al clickear un botón, poder obtener diferentes valores de elementos que estarían en el div que contiene a este botón. Es este caso quiero sacar la info del **"1:"** Lo estoy haciendolo de esa manera, pero no sé si exista otra forma más facil o mejor. Gracias de antemano.

[image: Codigo en JS]

Comment: Hola, Ulises. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito a realizar un [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, considera colocar como texto el código que presentas en la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder al valor de un nodo tienes que poner array[numero de nodo], por ejemplo:

```js
let array = ["yo", "tu", "el", "nosotros", "vosotros", "ellos"];

for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```